# PHP Fatal error when trying to install Laravel 5 with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to run composer to install Laravel 5.0.14, and am also trying to test this code out in Jenkins using the Jenkins php-template.

Whenever I run `composer update`, I get the following error:

```
Error Output: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Foundation\Application::redirectIfTrailingSlash() 
  in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Demo/workspace/bootstrap/start.php on line 16
```

If I remove the offending line in start.php, I obtain the following error when attempting to run `composer update`:

```
Error Output: PHP Catchable fatal error: 
  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectEnvironment() 
   must be an instance of Closure, array diven, called in 
   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Demo/workspace/bootstrap/start.php on line 32 
     and defined in 
   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Demo/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate
   /Foundation/Application.php
 on line 402
```

This is my **composer.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.14",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*@dev",
        "theseer/fxsl": "1.0.*@dev",
        "theseer/phpdox": "0.6.6",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.4.6",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.0.0",
        "h4cc/phpqatools": "dev-master",
        "phploc/phploc": "2.0.2",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.13.0",
    "patchwork/utf8": "1.2.1",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "v2.0.1",
        "mayflower/php-codebrowser": "1.1.0-beta1",
        "pear/console_commandline": "dev-trunk",
        "pear/log": "dev-master",
        "pear/pear_exception": "1.0.0",
        "phing/phing": "2.6.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I can run `composer update --no-scripts`.

I've searched for any composer.php files with `sudo find . -print | grep -i 'compiled.php'`. The only one I have is

```
./vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Tests/Fixtures/php/services9_compiled.php
```

which does not correspond with the compiled.php file several other people have suggested deleting for other people who have had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using a Laravel 4 composer.json. One of the big changes from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5 is the usage of namespaces. 
Also a lot of paths have been modified, so just installing Laravel 5 over an existing Laravel 4 is not possible. 
Better to install a fresh Laravel 5 and follow this guide:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

For reference here is my composer.json (notice the psr-4 in the autoload section)

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Comment: The error is actually from a removed function: 
http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-4.1 -> Removing Redirect Trailing Slash

Comment: Changing the Laravel version to 4.1.* and following the upgrade steps listed worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The composer file could be very well be 30 days older and not updated.

You would have to run this command from the path of the code folder using either a vitrtual box or cmd/gitbash/terminal:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

once downloaded, move the composer.phar file to the composer folder , normally its located at:

```
sudo mv composer.phar usr/bin/local/composer
```

then run the `composer update` to regenerate the autoloaded files.

Comment: After running these commands, I still get the `redirectIfTrailingSlash()` error described above when trying to run `composer update`